# Arduino GSM library phonenumber position

Tags: arduino, gsm

Using the Arduino GSM library to get authenticated call and sms.
I want to store position (one byte) of the authorized phone number not the phonenumber (many bytes).

But GetAuthorizedSms do not give me position, just phone number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in sms.cpp you can see that they use gsm.ComparePhoneNumber(i, ph) to compare the phonenumber on position i with the one you have.

```
byte get_phonenr_position(char *ph)
{
    byte i;
    for(i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
        if (gsm.ComparePhoneNumber(i, ph))
            return i;
    return 0;
}
```

should work but is not so efficient as you have to ask the module via the serial interface. I have added a variable `last_authorized` to the `SMSGSM` (and `CallGSM`) class:

```
sms.cpp:
                     // phone numbers are identical
                     // authorization is OK
                     // ---------------------------
+                    last_authorized = i;
                     ret_val = GETSMS_AUTH_SMS;
                     break;  // and finish authorization
                 }
sms.h:
      char GetAuthorizedSMS(byte position, char *phone_number, char *SMS_text, byte max_SMS_len,
                           byte first_authorized_pos, byte last_authorized_pos);
     char DeleteSMS(byte position);
+    // set by CallStatusWithAuth
+    byte last_authorized;
};
```

and read that variable from my SMSGSM instance. (For CallGSM I have done the same).